# dataWithContentsOfURL - What is expected from the server?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am trying to create NSData with the contents of an URL:

```
NSString *theUrl = [NSString stringWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1:8090"]; 
NSError *connectionError = nil; 
NSData *inData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theUrl] options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&connectionError];
NSInteger code = [connectionError code];
if (code != 0)
{
    NSString *locDesc = [NSString stringWithString:[connectionError localizedDescription]];
    NSString *locFail = [NSString stringWithString:[connectionError localizedFailureReason]];
    NSLog(@"Error: %d %@ %@", code, locDesc, locFail);
}
else if ([inData length] == 0)
{
    NSLog(@"No data");
}
```

I have a super simple Java http server running on the local host that returns Hello World to a client:

```
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream()); // s is the socket
os.writeBytes(new String("Hello World\0"));
os.flush();
os.close();
s.close();
```

When pointing Google Chrome to http://127.0.0.1:8090 it displays Hello World as expected so data *is* sent back. When I run the objective-c code the inData is empty (0x0, data length is 0), and the error code is 0 so I don't have an error to inspect. If I change theUrl to "http://www.google.com" it seems works fine as the data length becomes > 0.

So my question is why inData is empty when I go the to local http-server. Does the stream have to be terminated with a specific data sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little more context would be useful, but a wild guess is that your "super simple" HTTP server does not send any headers or not the ones expected by NSURL.

Have you tried `curl -i  http://127.0.0.1:8090` to see what the output actually looks like?

Comment: Great command! The output is Hello World and nothing else. That is also what I thought I would be able to catch on the device. Can't I use dataWithContentsOfURL to read plain text? I am planning to read JSON data which I will return from the super simple server. Do you think I need to add headers? What if I would just read an image from the URL. In that case no headers are set, right?

Comment: Actually, if return the following, then it works. 

"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\nHello World\0\n"

Comment: Don't you need two `\n`to separate the headers from the payload?

Answer (score 1):

Is the server outputting an HTTP status code like it's supposed to? If the response doesn't contain a 200 status indicating that the request was completed successfully, that might be causing `dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:` to fail.

Comment: Actually I am just returning what you see: "Hello World". Nothing else. I am planning to return JSON data, and want to parse it on the device later. Do I still have to send HTTP status?

Comment: Actually, if return the following, then it works. 

"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\nHello World\0\n"